# Check If Phone Number Exists in Auth Table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to android mobile application development, and I am developing an Android mobile application using Kotlin with Firebase integration. In the below function I am checking if the previously authenticated phone number (Firebase) already exists in the auth table or not to avoid sending another SMS and take the user right away to Home Activity. I am struggling to get it to work like expected.

```
private fun checkmobile() {

    dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")

    dbReference.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(buildString {
        append("+").append(country_code_picker.selectedCountryCode)
            .append(txtPhone.text.toString())
    })
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo::class.java)
                if (user==null) {
                    ShowMessage("Exists")
                    Log.e("Mobile:", buildString {
                        append("+").append(country_code_picker.selectedCountryCode)
                            .append(txtPhone.text.toString())
                    })
                } else {
                    ShowMessage("Doesn't exist")
                    Log.e("Mobile:", buildString {
                        append("+").append(country_code_picker.selectedCountryCode)
                            .append(txtPhone.text.toString())
                    })
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(rror: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using this way to detect if the user is already signed in? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: What isn't working about this code? Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a lousy interactive debugger, so it's best if you can tell us exactly what each line does, and what you expected it to do. Specifically: we have no way of knowing what the `buildString` method outputs. Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded phone number? Also edit your question to include the JSON at `/users` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @frank van puffelen Thanks for your reply. I am already using this routine to check if the user is logged in and has a valid token or not, but here it's quite different as if the user is logged out and is registered in the auth table, SMS will be sent out if `verifyphonenumber` function called though

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen when I exported the JSON from my Real Time Database, I found that the file has "Null" only